# fatal: Authentication failed for repo_b while doing a git fetch repo_b master (currently on repo_a 's master which is forked from repo_b)

Tags: git, authentication, git-remote, git-fetch

I'm currently on `repo_a` 's `master` , `repo_a` is forked from `repo_b`.

While trying to resolve conflicts, I am doing a `git fetch repo_b master`

I'm getting a following error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'repo_b's url'
```

I tried unsetting my `user.name` and `user.password` in `git config --global` , even after that I am getting the same error.

Could anyone please let me know where I am wrong ?

Comment: Does it ask for your password when you fetch?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It didn't, when I do `git pull` (from repo_a's master, it's updating without password prompt, only when I do `git fetch repo_b master` , it is giving the errot)

Comment: So the pull works, but the fetch doesn't? May you post the two commands you're using?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `git pull` on current branch only brings changes that are made on `repo_a` 's `master. `git fetch` `repo_b's url` `master` is the command that is not working. here, `repo_a` is actually forked from `repo_b`.

Comment: Which repo is "local" and which repo is the "remote"?

Comment: repo_a and repo_b - both are remote, while syncing them, I got conflicts. for that, I am trying to fetch changes from repo_b to my local repo_a and trying to merge.

Comment: What git url scheme are you using?